# MOSS 2007 KeepAlive File

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a standard MOSS 2007 Web Site (MOSS Terminology: Application and a SiteCollection)

I located the home directory (as its setup in IIS)

```
C:\InetPub\wwwRoot\wss\VirtualDirectories\nyMOSSApp.com:80
```

I created a keepAlive.aspx file in this directory. The contents is very basic... but its a valid winForm file (not a 0KB File)

When I try navigate to the file, I get a 404 (File not found).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, for some reason SharePoint requires an IISReset when you add a physical file to the file system. Blasted SharePoint :)